# ADODB query timeout

Tags: vba, ms-access, adodb

I am trying to open a query, which is timing out. I have tried setting the timeout property, but it doesn't seem to want to accept it.

The query takes 34 seconds to execute using MS-SQL Server Management window (SQL Server 2005), so I know I need to increase the timeout.

Current code:

```
Public Function retRecordSet(StrSQL)
Dim cmd ' as new ADODB.Command
Dim rs 'As New ADODB.Recordset

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cmd.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
cmd.CommandText = StrSQL
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
Set rs = cmd.Execute

Set retRecordSet = rs
End Function
```

I have also tried setting the timeout of the connection itself `CurrentProject.Connection.CommandTimeout = 120`, but if I query the value right after this command, it remains at 30

Connection properties:

> Provider=Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=MyServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Data Provider=SQLOLEDB.1

```
Data Source Object Threading Model = 1
Multiple Results = 3
Multiple Parameter Sets = False
SQL Support = 283
Catalog Location = 1
Catalog Term = database
Catalog Usage = 15
Rowset Conversions on Command = True
Extended Properties = 
Cache Authentication = True
Encrypt Password = 
Persist Encrypted = 
Persist Security Info = False
Asynchronous Processing = 0
Connect Timeout = 600
Protection Level = 
Prompt = 4
Mode = 
Location = 
Locale Identifier = 1033
Impersonation Level = 
Window Handle = 
Data Source = MyServer
User ID = 
Password = 
Integrated Security = SSPI
Mask Password = 
Initial Catalog = MyDatabase
Lock Owner = 
Bind Flags = 
General Timeout = 0
Data Provider = SQLOLEDB.1
Autocommit Isolation Levels = 4096
Unique Reshape Names = False
```

Comment: Take a look at this blog post: http://codingjourney.blogspot.com/2008/11/ado-connection-timeout-command-or.html

Comment: @HK1, you'll see I set the command timeout on the ADODB Command to 0 (Infinite timeout)

Comment: Not sure why the 30 second timeout remains, seems very strange.  What happens if you call 'rs.open cmd' instead of 'set rs = cmd.execute' passing in your command object as the source. Just curious if you run into the same issue there?

Comment: How is your connection setup? When I use ADO connections I always use explicit connections that I create so I'm not accustomed to using CurrentProject.Connection. Is this an ADP?

Comment: @HK1,  yes, it's an ADP (and I can't change that)

Comment: @SeanCheshire just out of interest - does `CommandTimeout = 0` mean to set no time out?

Answer (score 34):

Not sure if you already got over the problem but I had the same issue.
I'm doing it with Recordset.Open SQL_String, Connection.

And before that I just set the timeout property, not on the Recordset or Command but on the Connection object:

```
Connection.CommandTimeout = 0
```

Answer (score 16):

from  http://codingjourney.blogspot.com/2008/11/ado-connection-timeout-command-or.html

> The Solution
>
> You must also set the `commandTimeout` property on the
>   `ADODB.Command` or `ADODB.Recordset` being used. Otherwise those objects
>   will use the default time limit of 30 seconds because they do not
>   inherit the time limit from the associated `ADODB.Connection` instance.
>
> Example Using VBScript in ASP 3:
>
> ```
> set con = createObject("ADODB.Connection")
> con.open connectionString
> con.commandTimeout = 60
> set command = createObject("ADODB.Command")
> command.activeConnection = con
> command.commandType = adCmdText
> command.commandText = sql
> command.commandTimeout = 60
> command.execute
> response.write command.commandTimeout 'This is now 60 seconds.
> ```

Comment: About this: "You must also set the commandTimeout property on the ADODB.Command or ADODB.Recordset being used." 
 I'm not seeing a CommandTimeout property or method on the ADODB.Recordset object.

Answer (score 1):

For OLEDB do you not need to specify the timout on the connection :-

> Provider=Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0;Persist Security Info=False;Data
>   Source=MyServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial
>   Catalog=MyDatabase;Data Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Connect Timeout=30