# Query Time Out Expired Even Though I've set the command timeout to 2 mins

Tags: sql, excel, vba

This is the complete code and you can see I've defined command time out.

```
Sub Import_Data()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim clearRange As Range
    Dim cn As Object ' ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As Object ' ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim strConnection As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Working")

    ' Find the last row with data in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Make sure lastRow is at least 3
    If lastRow < 3 Then
        lastRow = 3
    End If

    ' Define the range to be cleared from row 3 to the last row for all columns
    Set clearRange = ws.Range("A3:" & ws.Cells(lastRow, ws.Columns.Count).Address)

    ' Clear the contents of the range in one operation
    clearRange.ClearContents

    MsgBox "Cleaning Done.!"

    ' Open connection for SQL DB
    strConnection = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=dbSC;Data Source=GBLWDBS04PV\DBSC;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=INBAN07NB245GWK;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;"
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") ' Create an ADODB.Connection object
    cn.Open strConnection
    cn.CommandTimeout = 120 ' Set the CommandTimeout property here
    
    ' Get user-selected values from "Insight-Summary" sheet
    Dim selection As String
    selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Insights-Summary").Range("E4").Value
    Dim code As String
    Dim formattedCode As String
    code = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Insights-Summary").Range("E6").Value
    If Len(code) = 1 Then
        formattedCode = "0" & code
    Else
        formattedCode = code
    End If
    Dim warehouse As String
    warehouse = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Insights-Summary").Range("E8").Value

    ' Build the SQL query based on the user-selected values
    strSql = "SELECT ltrim(rtrim(w.wpprod)) AS Part_no, w.wppawh AS Whse, p.PAMAN AS Manufacture_Part, LEFT(w.WPABC, 1) AS ABC_Code, sp.[ProductManager] AS PMID, " & _
             "SKAVAIL_SALE AS Current_Inventory_Qty, (SKAVAIL_SALE) * UnitCost AS Current_Inventory_Value, PHPORN AS PO_Number, PDPROD AS Farnell_Part, PHOSTS AS Order_Status, PDLINE AS PO_Line, " & _
             "TRY_CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), PHCRDT) AS DATE) AS PO_CREATE, PDADVD AS PO_Adv_Date, PHSUPP AS Supplier, PDQORD AS Total_Qty_Ordered, PDQOS AS PO_Qty_Outstanding, PDCOST AS PO_Line_Cost, TRY_CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), PDRQDT) AS DATE) AS PO_Required, " & _
             "sp.ObsoleteFlag AS ObsoleteFlag, dw.SupplierLeadTime AS SupplierLeadTime, pb.PDSCDE as Supplier_PartNo,pb.PDCRUS as PO_Creator,lgt.[SS_AVAIL_QTY], CASE WHEN pb.PHWHSE = 'UK1' THEN GB_Buyer WHEN pb.PHWHSE = 'LG1' THEN LG_Buyer ELSE '' END AS Buyer_Code " & _
             "FROM gba.whprod w " & _
             "INNER JOIN gba.whstok_combined s ON w.wpas400 = s.skas400 AND w.wpprod = s.skprod AND w.wppawh = s.skpawh " & _
             "INNER JOIN gba.inprd1 p ON w.wpas400 = p.paas400 AND w.wpprod = p.paprod " & _
             "LEFT JOIN gba.insupp i ON w.wpas400 = i.spas400 AND w.wpprod = i.spprod AND w.wppawh = i.sppawh AND 1 = i.spprms " & _
             "INNER JOIN [dbSC].[agg].[SKU_By_Period_ProvisionHistoryWorkFile_WithTodays_PO_SO_MTDSales_info] sp ON w.wpprod = sp.Product " & _
             "INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_orbt_DualWhse] dw ON sp.Product = dw.wpprod " & _
             "INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_orbt_pobook pb ON w.wpprod = pb.PDPROD AND w.WPPAWH = pb.WHPAWH " & _
             "INNER JOIN [dbLogility].[Logility].[IP_Time_Series_EU] AS LGt ON LGt.[FCST_1_ID] = w.wpprod AND LGt.[FCST_2_ID] = CASE WHEN WPPAWH IN ('UK1', 'GB1') THEN 'GB' ELSE 'LG' END " & _
             "WHERE w.wpas400 = 'GBA' and PHPORN NOT IN (SELECT PO_Number FROM [Depth].[Investment_Purchase_Orders])"

    ' Apply user-selected filters
    Select Case selection
        Case "Buyer"
            strSql = strSql & " AND ("
            strSql = strSql & "(pb.PHWHSE = 'UK1' AND GB_Buyer IN ('" & formattedCode & "', '" & formattedCode & "a', '" & formattedCode & "n')) OR (pb.PHWHSE = 'LG1' AND LG_Buyer IN ('" & formattedCode & "', '" & formattedCode & "a', '" & formattedCode & "n'))"
            strSql = strSql & ")"
        Case "Supplier"
            strSql = strSql & " AND PHSUPP IN ('" & formattedCode & "')"
    End Select

    strSql = strSql & " AND pb.PHOSTS IN ('SENT', 'PART')"

    ' Apply warehouse condition based on user-selected warehouse
    Select Case warehouse
        Case "UK1"
            strSql = strSql & " AND pb.PHWHSE IN ('UK1') AND w.wppawh IN ('UK1')"
        Case "GB1"
            strSql = strSql & " AND pb.PHWHSE IN ('GB1') AND w.wppawh IN ('GB1')"
        Case "LG1"
            strSql = strSql & " AND pb.PHWHSE IN ('LG1') AND w.wppawh IN ('LG1')"
    End Select

    strSql = strSql & " AND LEFT(w.WPABC, 1) IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')AND w.WPABC NOT IN ('AN', 'BN', 'CN')"
    strSql = strSql & " AND lgt.ROWNBR = 1 " & _
             "ORDER BY w.wpprod, PDADVD ASC;"

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    cn.Open strConnection
    rs.Open strSql, cn

    ' Paste the retrieved data starting from a dynamic cell
    Dim startCell As Range
    Set startCell = ws.Range("B2")
    startCell.CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    
    ' Delete records from "Complete_Result" sheet starting from row 3
    Dim completeResultSheet As Worksheet
    Set completeResultSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Complete_Result")
    lastRow = completeResultSheet.Cells(completeResultSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow >= 3 Then
        completeResultSheet.Rows("3:" & lastRow).Delete
    End If
    
    Dim LogForecastSheet As Worksheet
    Set LogForecastSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LVSDB_RESULTANT_FCST")
    lastRow1 = LogForecastSheet.Cells(LogForecastSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow1 >= 3 Then
        LogForecastSheet.Rows("3:" & lastRow1).Delete
    End If      
    MsgBox "Data Populated!"
End Sub
```

I tried increasing command timeout to 120 seconds but the error is appearing in within 40 seconds only.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574524/adodb-query-timeout

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.